# Completely uninstall a program on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-center, uninstall, software-uninstall

I'm new to the Linux community and I recently switched from windows to linux. Of course, I'm used to uninstall my softwares using the obvious ways on Windows, and I even knew that I should manually delete some of the files. But I'm lost on Ubuntu. So many folders that I don't even understand what they are for.

Many of the answers I've seen here said to uninstall from the software center or using the terminal. And all that said use the terminal gave an example either too complicated for me to understand or for another software. I've tried to uninstall from the software center and it did uninstall but when I performed a check to see if it was really gone, to my horror the software opened up even after I uninstalled it.

For e.g, I installed Deluge and Cairo dock and I wanted to remove them. I did from software center but both are still opening and working as if I never uninstalled them. I even followed some instructions for command lines regarding Cairo dock, but it's still here.

Comment: This behavior is not normal on Ubuntu. Usually both Software Centre and Terminal uninstall the program just fine. You can try Synaptic Package manager and see if that helps you. Synaptic does not come bundled with Ubuntu as far as I know, so you'll need to install it, but it's a great program. If you are unsure how to use it, scroll down to "Uninstall" in this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

Comment: In Synaptic Package Manager there is also a function called "Complete Removal". But even a normal uninstall using Ubuntu Software Center should be fine, so either you are doing something wrong, or there is something wrong with your system.